# Почему не "человеки" или не "людь"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, этимология, выбор-слов, словообразование

Многие отвечают на такой вопрос проблемой в **неудобном** произношении. Но ведь если с самого момента **зарождения** слова "человек", люди говорили "**человеки**" во **множественном** числе, то все бы уже давно привыкли к такому звучанию. Из-за чего люди придумали себе **другое** название?

Comment: Видимо, это сложилось _стихийно_ - в процессе регионального размежевания: где-то и сейчас широко употребляются слова _чоловіки_, _людина_ :)

Comment: Полюбопытствуйте, зайдите — здесь сотни и сотни примеров употребления этого «неудобного» слова —  http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такое мнение:

> Явление, называемое супплетивизмом основ, является одним из древнейших
>   в любом языке. Супплетивизм ведёт свою историю с тех времён, когда
>   абстрактное мышление человека находилось в зачаточном состоянии. В те
>   времена ещё не было категории множественного числа, так что проблему
>   множественности чего-либо нельзя было решить изменением окончания.
>   "Один конь" не понимался как единичное проявление общего понятия
>   "кони", а "несколько коней" не понималось как множественное проявление
>   того, что в единичном виде является одним конём. С людьми же ещё
>   сложнее. Ведь мы ещё можем представить миллион одинаковых пластиковых
>   тазиков, сотню вроде как похожих по виду и качествам арабских
>   скакунов, а также целый лес, состоящий из отдельных деревьев, но
>   каждый человек видится существом индивидуальным, личностью. Это лишь в
>   нынешние времена в произведениях фантастических можно встретить
>   множество клонов, а у людей древних даже такой возможности не было.
>   Потому и в русском языке, и в английском, и наверняка в ещё
>   каких-нибудь понятия "человек" и "люди" выражаются неоднокоренными
>   словами. В старославянском языке имелась и форма множественного числа
>   слова человек, но она не прижилась в древнерусском языке. Это говорит
>   о том, что психологический аспект, здравый смысл стоит для носителя
>   языка выше "удобства" образования грамматических форм.*

http://otvet.expert/pochemu-chelovek-vo-mnozhestvennom-chisle-budet-lyudi-a-ne-cheloveki-1188511

В  супплетивной паре слов ***человек - люди*** существительное «человек» потеряло форму множественного числа «человеки» из-за малоупотребляемости. В русском языке имелись формы единственного и множественного числа слов «люд — люди». С течением времени существительное «люд» стало собирательным и начало функционировать в языке как самостоятельное слово. Тогда форма множественного числа существительного «люди» нашла себе пару в лице формы единственного числа «человек».

Comment: Было бы здорово, если бы ответ также включал причину трансформации слова "люд" в собирательное. С какой целью нужно было менять роль слова, а потом, спохватываясь, искать ему замену? Также возник вопрос по содержанию цитаты. Если отсутствие абстрактного мышления препятствовало возникновению множественных форм, то почему в древнерусском языке была форма, которая утратилась, а не наоборот — изначально отсутствовала, а по мере развития языка не появилась бы? Это бы больше соответствовало мысли автора.Как Вы считаете, Людмила?

Comment: Не думаю, что в этом больше логики.Множественное число человеки было, но сложно себе представить много одинаковых особей, потому его стали избегать.Как раз абстрактное мышление и привело к появлению категории собирательности, когда мы видим не каждого человека отдельно, а большое количество, из этой категории согласование в числе: пришли пять человек/ пришло пять человек (личности интересуют или их количество)

Comment: Поскольку я интересовался Вашим мнением, а Вы им поделились, не стану развязывать спор. Был мой вопрос, на него Вы дали ответ. Но замечу, что вся эта гипотеза для меня не убедительна. Сколько есть письменность, столько времени людей в ней рассматривают именно как совокупность. Да и наскальные фрески преимущественно далеко не портретные, а как раз групповые. Но развитие этой темы грозит выйти за рамки форума о русском языке, поэтому просто обозначу, что, как минимум, из этих соображений я не склонен полагаться на приведённый Вами источник и позволю себе усомниться в его версии.

Answer (score 0):

Шесть разных понятий: человек, человече, человеки, люди, люд, людина.
В Русском языке эти шесть понятий составляют понятие "сословие".
Сословие: человек и люди.
Человек - это одушевлённое существо с возможностью познания себя и окружающего мира.
Люди - множественное число существа "человек".
Единственное и множественное числа. Человек: человече и людина. Люди: люд и человеки.
Кратко. Человече - единица, своеобразность. Людина - один из некой общности. Люд - множество в обобщении (но тут придётся подтягивать понятия "народ", "население", "человечество"...). Человеки - множество на отдельных единицах существ...
Там ещё три ряда вниз идут, но я ещё не во всём разобрался.